# VBA Copy Rows from One worksheet to Another (Syntax error?)

Tags: vba, excel

I have data on one worksheet named "Master" that I am trying to conditionally copy over each row to a workbook called "Auto" based on whether the original row has "Hire" in column A.

```
Sub Macro2()
Dim lr As Long, lr2 As Long, r As Long
lr = Sheets("Master").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lr2 = Sheets("AUTO").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For r = lr To 2 Step -1
        Select Case Range("A" & r).Value
           Case Is = "Hire"
           Rows(r).Copy Destination:=Sheets("AUTO").Range("A" & lr2 + 1)
            lr2 = Sheets("AUTO").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        End Select
    Next r
End Sub
```

When I run the macro, however, it does not populate the second worksheet.

Comment: What is the **Active** worksheet when you run this macro? Your `Case` switch is using ambiguously named `Range("A" & r).Value` which refers to the ActiveWorksheet. If you step through your code, what do you observe happening at the Case switch?

Comment: Likewise, `Rows(r).Copy` also refers tot he *Active* worksheet, so does `Rows.Count`, etc.. Whenever working with multiple worksheet or workbook objects, it is much easier to declare proper variables to represent and keep track of each, and **fully-qualify** your range objects. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you are just trying to find the word "Hire" in Column A and paste the row to another sheet.

This may work better for you.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim rws As Long, rng As Range, c As Range

    Set ws = Worksheets("AUTO")
    Set sh = Worksheets("Master")

    With sh
        rws = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(rws, 1))
    End With

    For Each c In rng.Cells
        If c = "Hire" Then
            c.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: This was perfect. Thank you! I am very new to VBA and each new success is a great feeling!